# How to render a list of records in a nested manner Angular async pipe

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

How to render a single list of records in a nested manner in Angular? I have an array of appointment records. I want to group the appointments by day. This is simple if you're generating the HTML yourself with nested loops in Javascript but I don't know how to do this in Angular *ngFor from a single list (nesting *ngFors with multiple lists is easy enough).

Here is a simplified version of the problem. First, the data  model.

```
export interface Appointment {
    scheduled: Date;
    client: string;
}
  appointments$: Observable<Appointment[]>;
```

Here is how I would like to render it, grouped by day, and then a list of client names below each day.

[image]

Then finally here is the HTML to generate that picture.

```
 <ion-item-group>
    <ion-item-divider>
      <ion-label>MON 15</ion-label>
    </ion-item-divider>
  
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Alfred Futter</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Around the Trumpet</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-item-group>
  
  <ion-item-group>
    <ion-item-divider>
      <ion-label>TUE 16</ion-label>
    </ion-item-divider>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Antonio Taco</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Berglunds</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Blondel and Sons</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-item-group>
```

So now the problem is I have one array of appointments which is typically iterated in Angular like this:

```
<ion-item-group *ngFor="let appt of appointments$ | async">
...
<ion-item-group>
```

But this just generates the outer list of ion-item-group. How do I also generate the inner subgroup of ion-items under each day using the appts.scheduled field to group?

Thank you.

Edit: my own solution per request of @E.Maggini below. First I munged the service itself to group the appointments by day, like this:

```
    appointments = Object.values(_.groupBy(appointments, a => a.scheduled.getDate()));
```

(yes I know just getDate() is not enough, this is just for proof of concept)

Then the following HTML suffices to render it exactly as desired:

```
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item-group *ngFor="let apptsOneDay of appointments$ | async">
      <ion-item-divider>
        <ion-label>{{apptsOneDay[0].scheduled}}</ion-label>
      </ion-item-divider>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let appt of apptsOneDay">
        <ion-label>{{appt.name}}</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-item-group>    
  </ion-list>
```

I would much prefer to operate on the Observable<Appointments[]> returned by the service using RXJS operators per the suggestion @GaurangDhorda but I can't get the operator chain to work.

Comment: can you add sample raw data too ?

Comment: You can use groupBy operator rxjs by date and mergeMap all sub group data

Comment: Please post code of what you have tried so far

Comment: @E.Maggini I grouped the data in the service returning the appointment list using lodash, and then the Angular HTML, I used two nested *ngFor's to render. This results in exactly what I needed but seems ugly. To post that code, should I add it as an answer below, or should I edit my question? It's not a small edit.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda After researching what your answer meant I believe that is the right way because it uses operators on the observable instead of munging the data returned from the service. But after many attempts along the lines of ```.pipe(
  mergeMap(x => x),   groupBy(appt => appt.scheduled.getDate()),   mergeMap(group => group.pipe(toArray())),   map(x => [x]));``` (and corresponding nested ngFor's in the HTML) I still cannot get it to work.

Comment: @E.Maggini I saw that SO said it's OK to edit the question with additional info, so I added what you requested. Thanks.

Comment: @royappa here is demo using groupBy date observable pipe https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-eh6tpr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts have a look at this. Thank you.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda I got your code working in my app. It is perfect! Please post your excellent answer so I can accept it. Many thanks for writing a full example.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda Unfortunately I cannot, as this is just a personal project. I did try to use the coffee link in your profile but it doesn't take international payments. And please be careful, stack overflow does not allow job solicitations, they might ban you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete Working demo in this [Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-eh6tpr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Basically, All you need to do pipe your appointment observable with groupBy, mergeMap, and toArray rxjs operators so, that you got your groupBy date data and and You can use this data into the template and traverse using nested ngFor. Here is your observable pipe code..

```
appointment$: Observable<appointmentObservable[]> = of(
this.appointmentData).pipe(
   mergeMap((parentData) => parentData),
   groupBy((parentGroup) => parentGroup.scheduled.toLocaleDateString()),
   mergeMap((group) => this.reducePipe(group)),
   toArray()
);

reducePipe(group: GroupedObservable<string, appointment>) {
  return group.pipe(
    reduce(
      (acc, cur) => {
        acc.clients.push(cur);
          return acc;
        },
        { scheduled: new Date(group.key), clients: [] }
      )
     );
 }
```

In above code this line `parentGroup.scheduled.toLocaleDateString()` of groupBy operator is getting schedule date type data and we convert it to localString and pass it to next mergeMap pipe. Then we use reduce operator and again we convert stringDate to dateFormat date using `scheduled: new Date(group.key)` This line.

Now HTML is...

```
<ng-container *ngIf="appointment$ | async as appointments">
   <ion-item-group *ngFor="let appointment of appointments">
      <ion-item-divider>
         <ion-label>{{ appointment.scheduled | date: 'EEE dd' }}</ion-label>
      </ion-item-divider>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let userNames of appointment.clients">
         <ion-label>{{ userNames.client }}</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
   </ion-item-group>
</ng-container>
```

In above html we are using `appointment.scheduled | date: 'EEE dd'` date pipe of angular with format to transform date to your need like `MON 21`. Thank You.

Comment: I applied these ideas in my code and it works exactly as desired. This way I can transform the data returned from a service instead of modifying the service itself, so it's much cleaner. It was also instructive that you made a separate model appointmentObservable just for the View itself, which is a wholly separate question I had been wondering about. Thanks for sharing your time and expertise!

Comment: appointmentObservable is used here because of clients property is now array and in original appointment interface client interface is only a single string type. Thanks you too!!